# Не работают ссылки в корзине на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В открытой корзине не работает ни одна ссылка, ни ссылка на товары в корзине ни кнопка оформить заказ. В чем может быть проблема?
В песочнице сделал [аналогичный пример](https://codepen.io/EvgenStor/pen/drLyxX), ссылка работает как положено, на сайте установлен тот же скрипт открытия корзины но ссылки не работают.
Я так полагаю это из за return false; в скрипте, но если убрать, то корзина при закрытии закрывается и опять открывается. 
Помогите исправить? Хочется именно с эффектом слайда.
Инструкция:
В песочнице нажав на ссылку в примере перейдете на сайт, добавьте в корзину товар, откройте корзину, ссылка на товар и кнопка оформить заказ не будут работать.

```
    <script>
  $("#shop-basket").click(function() {
    $('.cart-content').slideDown(300);
    return false;
  });
  $(".close-x").click(function() {
    $('.cart-content').slideUp(300);
    return false;
  });
</script>

<style>
  #shop-basket {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #033d6f;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .cart-content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: cadetblue;
    height: 50px;
  }

  .total {
    webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  }

  .close-x {
    display: block;
    width: 22px;
    height: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 5px;
    left: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 101;
    background: #fb3840;
  }
</style>

<div id="shop-basket">
  <div class="header-cart ">кнопка</div>
</div><i class="icon-close close-x">x</i>

<div class="cart-content">
  <div class="subtotal">
    <div class="total">Итого: <strike>3 418,00</strike> 3 247,10 €</div>
    <a href="https://mirtechniki.net/shop/537901/desc/microsoft-surface-pro-i5-8gb-256gb-lte-2017">ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не хватает ссылки на сам сайт

Comment: ссылка в песочнице https://mirtechniki.net

Answer (score 1):

Проблему удалось устранить следующей конструкцией, и все стало работать как часы.

```
$(function () {
  $("#shop-basket").on("click", function(){
    $(".cart-content").slideDown(300);
  });

  $(document).on( "click", ".close-x", function(){
    $(".cart-content").slideUp(300);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что проблема кроется тут..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CbIPoK2513, подскажи название инспектора которым ты пользуешься

Comment: @Евгений Называется Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: CbIPoK2513, спасибо, я и не знал что Firefox инспектор на русском, даже пояснения ошибок, прикольно. По старинке Google Chrome пользовался

Comment: @Евгений Chrome для разработки, Firefox для души ;)